# C onefile program printing (on stdout) self complete source code

Tags: c

I hear 3 years ago problem and apparently have infinity solutions.
I want to find one of this infinity set.

**Problem:** Write program (have only one file example "selfsource.c") who printing on stdout self source code and exits.

All techniques all alowed. Anyone can help me?

Comment: It is definitely easier just to email your customer a copy of the file.

Comment: The search you wanted was http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine, I don't see an existing "write a quine in c" question, but the [code-golf] question surely has one or two (albeit harder to understand than strictly necessary). You might also be interested in Reflections on Trusting Trust (http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html).

Comment: @dmckee: at first you must know the this is qunie

Comment: @Svisstack: Certainly. No disapproval intended. SLaks had already given you the word, so I saw no need to repeat it. NB: It is not my down vote and I disagree with it.

Comment: @dmckee +1 for the link to Thompson's article. That was fun.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a program output a copy of itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479489/can-a-program-output-a-copy-of-itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a [Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29).

Wikipedia has an [example in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29#C).

Answer (score 2):

More examples than you could possibly need can be found at http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/self_c.txt.

Answer (score 0):

[Google](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=quine+program) for [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) programs.