# Could someone write a program that print the exactly code of the program

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a program output a copy of itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479489/can-a-program-output-a-copy-of-itself)

Could someone write a program that print the exactly code of the program

Comment: duplicate of [Can a program output a copy of itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479489/can-a-program-output-a-copy-of-itself) and many others

Comment: Numerous duplicates.  Search http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=quine

Comment: Sure, here it is:  (This is Python code, but it also works in Perl, Ruby and bash.)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm

This is probably what you are looking for.